# Best way to save to nsuserdefaults for custom class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

If I have a custom class Person which has three variables (which are propertized and synthesized):

```
NSString* theName;
float* theHeight;
int theAge;
```

Person instances are stored in an NSArray 'Group'. There is only one Group. What is the best way of storing and loading the Group in NSUserDefaults? (bearing in mind that float and int are not legal for NSUserDefaults)

Comment: Why aren't float and int legal?  `NSUserDefaults` has methods for both.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 45):

@Brad Smith's answer is not complete, and even is incorrect in some sense. We have to use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` as follows:

Make your class (for example in this case `Person`) to conform to protocol `NSCoding` and implement both the methods as:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:<key_for_property_name>];
        // as height is a pointer
        *self.height = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:<key_for_property_height>];
        self.age = [decoder decodeIntForKey:<key_for_property_age>];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:<key_for_property_name>];
    //as height is a pointer
    [encoder encodeFloat:*self.height forKey:<key_for_property_height>]
    [encoder encodeInt:self.age forKey:<key_for_property_age>];
}
```

Using `NSUserDefaults`

```
// Write to NSUserDefaults
NSData *archivedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:<your_class_object>];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:archivedObject forKey:<key_for_archived_object>];
[defaults synchronize];

// Read from NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *archivedObject = [defaults objectForKey:<key_for_archived_object>];
<your_class> *obj = (<your_class> *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedObject];
```

Comment: I wish I can upvote your answer to the top. Brad Smith is totally misleading.

Comment: @Kailash , so what's the use of the encode and decode methods? What encoder should I pass when instantiating it? Or is that automatically called when saving and reading?

Comment: @gdubs, yes those methods are called by os itself.

Answer (score 1):

I find implementing encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder quite boring, especially if you have many attributes in your class, and many classes to save to NSUserDefaults.

I create a library RMMapper (https://github.com/roomorama/RMMapper) to help save custom object into NSUserDefaults easier and more convenient.

To mark a class as archivable, just use: `#import "NSObject+RMArchivable.h"`

To save a custom object into NSUserDefaults:

```
#import "NSUserDefaults+RMSaveCustomObject.h"

NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults rm_setCustomObject:user forKey:@"SAVED_DATA"];
```

To get custom obj from NSUserDefaults:

```
user = [defaults rm_customObjectForKey:@"SAVED_DATA"];
```